# How do I print all passwords in Gnome Keyring (seahorse)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, passwords, gnome

I can access all passwords in my Gnome keyring just fine. Everything works ok. But in case things go awry, I'd like to backup all passwords on a piece of paper and store it elsewhere. However, I can't find any way to accomplish this. Is there some known way to get all usernames/logins and their passwords in some kind of list?

Since I'm trying to get my Chrome passwords in the first place any answer that partially answers the question for Chrome would also be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Chrome it should works

- Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select Settings.
- Click Show advanced settings.
- Click Manage saved passwords in the "Passwords and forms" section to see a list of all the usernames and passwords that have been saved.

more info in [google support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?p=settings_password&rd=1)

---

#### Update after the QA specification

It seems that at present google chrome do not provide a way to fully export in plain text the list of password, stored in an sqlite3 database on the hard disk... but we do not resign so fast.

It seems even that it exists a method when chrome is synchronized with the *google account* (Make sure that you have ticked Passwords in Advanced Sync Settings). You need also sqlite to read the database.

Start *chrome* with this option to have the database saved in plain way with the name `Login Data`

```
google-chrome --password-store=basic
```

*"Wait for a while until the data is synced (type `chrome://settings/passwords` in your address bar to make sure your passwords are showing):*
Close all the Chrome windows and export the table in text from the database

> sqlite3 -header -csv -separator "," ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login\ Data "SELECT * FROM logins" > ~/Passwords.csv

Notes:

- for *Google Chrome*: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data`
- for *Chromium*: `~/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data`

Reference:

- [Export chrome passwords](http://www.axllent.org/docs/view/export-chrome-passwords/)

Comment: Same problem, I can access all passwords but have to "Show" them individually. Can't display all of the at the same time in clear text.

Comment: Updated the answer... else you can always google a _"password dumper"_ _"password decryptor"_ ...

Comment: will this leave the passwords unencrypted? Or can I go back to encryption after dumping the passwords into a csv?

Comment: About the option when you used by the command-line [you can find](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/): `--password-store` Specifies which _password store_ to use (**detect, default, gnome, kwallet**). Choose another that doesn't start with "**d**" and it should works... :-).